# When I press escape key, the = key appears to be pressed instead

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have no idea what caused this, but as of yesterday or the day before, when I press ESC, the = key seems to be pressed instead. This happens across all programs. And it doesn't seem like the ESC key has been remapped (if this is the proper term) to be =, but that my computer is recognizing a press of ESC as a press of =. For instance, when I have the "Keyboard Layout Chart" up on my screen and I press ESC, = lights up orange. All other keys are working correctly.

Any thoughts on what happened or how to fix it? Is my keyboard just going bad? (The laptap is about 8 years old.)

I have Ubuntu 14.10.

EDIT: My keyboard seems to be fine, at least physically. I followed [Fabby's directions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/560422/when-i-press-escape-key-the-key-appears-to-be-pressed-instead#comment770122_560422) (thanks!) and got 0x01 0x81 after pressing ESC.

Comment: Is your keyboard going bad??? Before you try to go to the console, remember that [Ctrl][Alt][F7] brings you back (just remember: **[Ctrl][Alt][F7]**) Now press: [Ctrl][Alt][F1] to go to a console.  In there, log in under an admin user, and type `showkey --scancodes` If you press [esc] and you get 0x01 0x81 your keyboard is definitely working.  Please report back what you got.

Comment: Thanks! Keyboard is not going bad - I updated the question.

Comment: Can you do a `xev | grep -A2 --line-buffered '^KeyRelease' | sed -n '/keycode /s/^.*keycode \([0-9]*\).* (.*, \(.*\)).*$/\1 \2/p'` and see whether the output gives you "9 Escape" 3 times if you press it 3 times?

Comment: Yep, I got "9 escape" after doing that. However, after exiting that program, the problem has gone away. Would that command have fixed it? I guess I should have checked to make sure it was still happening before I tried it.  But I'm happy no matter the cause. Not having a working escape key was annoying.

Comment: I'll convert the comments to an answer.  Please accept the answer and later when you've got more reputation, come back and upvote it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your keyboard going bad???

Before you try to go to the console, remember that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> brings you back (**just remember: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>**) Now press: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to go to a console. In there, log in under an admin user, and type `showkey --scancodes` If you press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and you get `0x01 0x81` your keyboard is definitely working.

After that, do a

```
xev | grep -A2 --line-buffered '^KeyRelease' | \
    sed -n '/keycode /s/^.*keycode \([0-9]*\).* (.*, \(.*\)).*$/\1 \2/p'
```

Comment: What really happened? How did it get fixed?

Comment: You should ask the OP...  Mine was only a diagnostic whether the keyboard was working...