# Involuntary key repeat in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: keyboard, hp

I run Ubuntu 16.04 as a Windows 10 dual boot on a HP with its built-in keyboard.

Specifications in picture

[image: Specifications in picture]

I noticed an annoying keyboard behaviour under Ubuntu. When I press a key, it can happen that the system repeats the key infinitely, even after I released the key. I think this bug only appears, if I press a key for a longer time, but the bug can't be always reproduced by pressing a key over an extended period of time.

This can happen with any key, but mostly I notice it with arrow keys (Annoyingly, sometimes one doesn't see anything, except that the program seems to be unresponsive, because the arrow key command overrules any further input). I can terminate the key repeat by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> or another arrow key.

I don't know, how to evoke this behaviour on purpose. It is not a computer problem per se - I have never noticed that behaviour, when using the Windows partition. It is also not a problem with the latest update - the problem exists for quite a while, I just happen to ask now.

I also tried [this keyboard test](https://askubuntu.com/a/561841/757139) from the related question section. Keys were shown as expected and the sticky key problem didn't appear. Which doesn't say much, since it sometimes does not happen for days.

Comment: There are a couple of items that you can check.  Please execute the command `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard stickykeys-enable` - this should return 'false'.  Also look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/760842/283721), and if you have a USB keyboard around, verify the problem is with the OS rather than the current keyboard

Comment: Thanks, for your answer,  Charles. I edited now that the keyboard is a built-in keyboard and doesn't appear in the Windows partition. The command you suggested returns as expected `false`.

Comment: I also checked that `keyboard input` is set to `IBus` as suggested by the other thread, you pointed out.

Comment: I think this problem has been reported twice over the last few days by other users but don't have links handy. I think it deserves closer scrutiny.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Sorry, if I gave the impression that this might be an update problem. Edited question now, that this is going on for quite a while.

Comment: @Piinthesky This problem might be with Kernel 4.13 which was available in September 2017 I believe. I've update the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948) with fix options if you'd like to check it out.

Comment: this problem is seen as of today with Ubuntu 21. 04

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
xset r rate 250 60
xkbset bouncekeys 50
```

Tweak the numbers.

Also try:

```
xset r off
```

See:

- [xset](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xset.1.html)
- [xkbset](https://faculty.missouri.edu/~stephen/software/#xkbset)

Comment: Thank you for your input. Although turning off the autorepeat is probably an option, I don't really want to do this, because I actually use in my daily routine this functionality. And I don't see the point in changing the autorepeat parameters. It is a random behaviour, as if the key is stuck from time to time in the keyboard - only it isn't. I can stop the involuntary repeat by pressing any other key and it never happens on the Windows partition of this dual-boot installation.

Comment: The source code to xkbset is available, @Mr.T. It may be possible to run a program that detects when repeated keys are happening and momentarily disables the repeater (similar to calling `xset r off` followed by `xset r on`). Definitely a hack and not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue using X2Go over VPN connection to Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.
Going to Settings->Universal Access and in the Typing section turning off Repeat Keys seemed to fix the problem for me.

Comment: I had forgotten about this problem. One of the updates must have eradicated this problem - I have not experienced it in the last year or two. Coming to think of it, probably the 18.04 update killed it in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem, **but** it seems, that the unwanted repeating only appears, when pressing a key too short. Try to press some keys very carefully, then it should work. If you hack your keys quick enough it comes to this issue. I don't know why, but there seems to be a minimum time, a key must be pressed.